# VBA to make cell with certain Text the active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a macro (VBA) to search all of column A for "Eastern Conference" and then make that cell the active cell.  The position of Eastern Conference moves as the data is being populated by a web query.  I originally recorded a CNTL+F function that worked when it was run as a macro, but when I assigned it to a button, I get a run-time error on it.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

So here is what I have so far. I am looking for Eastern Conference in the A column and then copying the info around it (50 rows below & 26 columns right) to a new location so that it doesn't matter if it moves from row to row based on the the web query results. I have Eastern Conference in the reference cell of DA100 because I could not get it to do anything when I was just using the text in the script - I am just worried it will find the copied Eastern Conference in the AA1 cell and then basically paste over itself every time.  So I want to make sure it only looks for the text from DA100 ("Eastern Conference") in the A column - so that it will never find it in the AA1 cell or the DA100 cell and copy the wrong data.

Thanks

```
    Sub STANDINGS_FIX()
'
' STANDINGS_FIX Macro
'

'
   Sheets("STANDINGS_DATA").Select
   Range("A40").Select
   Dim SearchValue As String
   SearchValue = "*" & Range("DA100").Value & "*"
   Cells.Find(What:=SearchValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
    ActiveCell.Resize(50, 26).Copy
    Range("AA1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("EVENT INFORMATION").Select
    MsgBox "STANDINGS UPDATED!!!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of your VBA code.  Show us what you have done so far.  Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like some minor tweaks to the recorded macro will solve the problem, but we can't help unless you **show your code**.

Answer (score 0):

Recorded macro code can get you started toward a solution but it rarely fits all situations after the fact. The worksheet's Find operation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) has several options remembered from the last time it was used and these need to be reset to the operational parameters that suit your situation.

Another option is an exact or wildcard match down column A looking for the term *"Eastern Conference"*.

```
With activesheet
    'Exact match (e.g. Eastern Conference):
    .cells(application.match("Eastern Conference", .columns("A"), 0), "A").select
    'Wildcard match (e.g. 2014 Eastern Conference Finals):
    .cells(application.match("*Eastern Conference*", .columns("A"), 0), "A").select
end with
```

One of those should get you the correct cell activated.

When you get your code working, consider posting some of it on [Code Review - Excel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) for help getting away from `.Select` and `ActiveCell` in favor of direct cell addressing and referencing.

Comment: So here is what I have so far.  I am looking for Eastern Conference in the A column and then copying the info around it to a new location so that it doesn't matter if it moves from the web query.  I have Eastern Conference in the reference cell - I am just worried it will find the copied Eastern Conference in the AA1 cell.

Comment: Sub STANDINGS_FIX()
'
' STANDINGS_FIX Macro
'

'
   Sheets("STANDINGS_DATA").Select
   Range("A40").Select
   Dim SearchValue As String
   SearchValue = "*" & Range("DA100").Value & "*"
   Cells.Find(What:=SearchValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
    ActiveCell.Resize(50, 26).Copy
    Range("AA1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("EVENT INFORMATION").Select
    MsgBox "STANDINGS UPDATED!!!"
End Sub

Comment: @LeeBlair - Your code shows up badly in comments. It would be better is you edited your original question as an **addendum:**.